# Pig Error: Unhandled internal error. Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I have just upgraded Pig 0.12.0 to 0.13.0 version on Hortonworks HDP 2.1

I am getting below error when I am trying to use XMLLoader in my script, even though I have registered piggybank already.

Script:

```
 A = load 'EPAXMLDownload.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Document') as (x:chararray);
```

Error:

```
dump A
2014-08-10 23:08:56,494 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2014-08-10 23:08:56,496 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-08-10 23:08:56,651 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-08-10 23:08:56,727 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, GroupByConstParallelSetter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier]}
2014-08-10 23:08:57,191 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2014-08-10 23:08:57,199 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2014-08-10 23:08:57,214 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-08-10 23:08:57,223 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
2014-08-10 23:08:57,247 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
```

Comment: Just check if the registered jar has Interface and/or class. Error says Pig is expecting Class, but it found an interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that pig decides the hadoop version depending on which context var you have set
HADOOP_HOME -> v1
HADOOP_PREFIX -> v2

If you use hadoop2, you need to recompile the piggybank (which is by default compiled for hadoop1)

1. go to pig/contrib/piggybank/java
2. $ ant -Dhadoopversion=23
3. then copy that jar over pig/lib/piggybank.jar

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still get the same error.

Comment: +1 for HADOOP_HOME -> v1 HADOOP_PREFIX -> v2 which i do not see in the pig documentation nor in the pig bash script

Answer (score 3):

A few more details because the other answers didn't work for me:

1. Git clone the pig git mirror https://github.com/apache/pig
2. cd into the cloned directory
3. if you've already built pig in the past in this directory, you should run a clean

   ```
   ant clean
   ```
4. build pig for hadoop 2

   ```
   ant -Dhadoopversion=23
   ```
5. cd into piggybank

   ```
   cd contrib/piggybank/java
   ```
6. again, if you've build piggybank before, make sure to clean out the old build files

   ```
   ant clean
   ```
7. build piggybank for hadoop 2 (same command, different directory)

   ```
   ant -Dhadoopversion=23
   ```

If you don't build pig first, piggybank will throw a bunch of "symbol not found" exceptions while compiling. In addition, since I had previously built pig for Hadoop 1 (accidentally), without running a clean, I ran into runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

Some times you may get problem after installing Pig like below:-

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
 at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.checkJobContextIfRunningFromBackend(HCatUtil.java:88)
 at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.setLocation(HCatLoader.java:162)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:540)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:322)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:199)
 at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:277)
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1367)
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1352)
 at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1341)
```

Many blogs suggest you to recompile the Pig by executing command:

```
ant clean jar-all -Dhadoopversion=23
```

or recompile piggybank.jar by executing below steps

```
cd contrib/piggybank/java

ant clean

ant -Dhadoopversion=23
```

**But this may not solve your problem big time**. The actual cause here is related to HCatalog. Try updating it!!. In my case, I was using Hive0.13 and Pig.0.13. And I was using HCatalog provided with Hive0.13.

Then I updated Pig to 0.15 and used separate hive-hcatalog-0.13.0.2.1.1.0-385 library jars. And problem was resolved....

Because later I identified it was not Pig who was creating problem rather it was Hive-HCatalog libraries. Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same error with Hadoop version 2.2.0.
The work around is, we have to register following jar files using the grunt shell.

The paths that i am gonna paste below will be according to the hadoop-2.2.0 version. Kindly find the jars according to your version.

/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/ hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar

/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar

Using the REGISTER command we have to register these jars along with piggybank.

Run the pig script/command now and revert if you face any issue.